# Go back browser button action

Tags: javascript

in my project I have included an additional go back button which code is:

```
<div class="button_1"><p><a href="test.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"];?>" class="button-link">Go back</a></div>
```

Is it possible that the browsers go back button performs (via javascript or any other programming language) the same action so that I don't need to add an additional go back button to my project?

Thanks upfront for the support!!!

Comment: JavaScript gives you all the required methods, you may look into the History API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Comment: The answer is not giving me the needed informations. With my posted code I can delete the history and go back by clicking on my additional go back button. Do you know how to perform exact this action via javascript or any other programming language and without having an additional go back button in the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (Javascript):

```js
document.getElementById('go-back').addEventListener('click', () => {
  history.back();
});
```

```html
<button id="go-back">Go back</button>
```

Comment: The answer is not giving me the needed informations. With my posted code I can delete the history and go back by clicking on my additional go back button. Do you know how to perform exact this action via javascript or any other programming language and without having an additional go back button in the project?

Answer (score 0):

## **You can do it with `window.history.back()`**

```html
<button onclick="window.history.back();">Go Back</button>
```

***Also you can `window.history.forward()` to go forward***

> Note: This function will work until you have a history in browser for
> the current tab

Comment: The answer is not giving me the needed informations. With my posted code I can delete the history and go back by clicking on my additional go back button. Do you know how to perform exact this action via javascript or any other programming language and without having an additional go back button in the project?